# Weka filteredClassifier arrayOutOfBoundsException

Tags: machine-learning, classification, weka, decision-tree

I am trying to use the filtered classifier on data of the following format:

`real,real,real,...,nominal`

where I have 138 real values and a single nominal string representing the class.
I am using J48 as the base classifier and the supervised discretization filter as follows:

```
Filter discretize = new weka.filters.supervised.attribute.Discretize();
FilteredClassifier fc = new FilteredClassifier(); 
discretize.setInputFormat(m_data);

J48 ft = new J48();
ft.setOptions(wekaOptions);
fc.setFilter(discretize);
fc.setClassifier(ft);

fc.buildClassifier(m_data);
```

Where `m_data` is my (labelled) training data with `m_data.setClassIndex(m_data.numAttributes()-1)` set. No problems (that I can see) here.
I serialize this model and load it later. I then use it to classify unseen/new data like so:

```
Instance unlabeledInstance = new DenseInstance(1.0,features);
unlabeledInstance.setDataset(m_instances); 
m_classifier.classifyInstance(unlabeledInstance);
```

where features is a `double[]` that follows the format of the input data, but with no nominal class value. Here `m_instances` is just loaded from the training data file with 
`m_instances.setClassIndex(m_instances.numAttributes()-1)` set.

However, when running `m_classifier.classifyInstance(unlabeledInstance)`, I receive an `arrayOutOfBoundsException` error. Can anyone shed any light on this?

The trace is:

```
07-13 15:15:35.383: W/System.err(30659): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=138; index=138
07-13 15:15:35.383: W/System.err(30659):    at weka.core.DenseInstance.value(DenseInstance.java:309)
07-13 15:15:35.383: W/System.err(30659):    at weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.Discretize.convertInstance(Discretize.java:1047)
07-13 15:15:35.383: W/System.err(30659):    at weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.Discretize.input(Discretize.java:389)
07-13 15:15:35.383: W/System.err(30659):    at weka.classifiers.meta.FilteredClassifier.distributionForInstance(FilteredClassifier.java:425)
07-13 15:15:35.383: W/System.err(30659):    at weka.classifiers.AbstractClassifier.classifyInstance(AbstractClassifier.java:72)
```

It looks like its expecting the class value to be set.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove the class value from `unlabeledInstance` (also, `m_instances.setClassIndex(m_instances.numAttributes()-1)` is thus not needed). When Weka classifies a test instance it only needs the features and not the class, so if you leave the class in the instance then Weka gets doesn't expect the extra entry in the array and gives you the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: The features that I pass into the new DenseInstance does not contain a any class value. It is a list of 138 doubles.

Comment: Aah right. Then you should just remove `m_instances.setClassIndex(m_instances.numAttributes()-1)`, because it sets the last feature as class, while it should just be a feature/double.

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved like this:
removing `discretize.setInputFormat(m_data);`. When you are using a filtered classifier, weka will call SetUp method that do it for you.
I was using a naivebayesUpdate NaiveBayes